# Create appointments in Outlook from CRM 4.0

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

A client has CRM 4.0 installation and has requested that when a status of an entity changes (or at any other event one might think of), an appointment should be created in Outlook. Is that doable at all?

Optimally, I'd like to add an activity of Appointment to an entity of Lead so that an appointment is created in Outlook for a certain person (preferably not the one that is editing CRM).

Having only limited experience with CRM 4.0 I'm not even sure if it's possible to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a workflow that is triggered when the status changes on the Lead. Add a step to the workflow to create an Appointment and set the "Required" field on the the appointment to the Owner of the Lead. The next time his Outlook synchronizes, it should appear in his calendar.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that **without** the Outlook sync client?

Comment: You would need to buy a 3rd party product or service to do that. I have seen them advertised (such as DXSync) but I have not used any of them. One of my clients just purchased an old laptop and left it at home running outlook all day to do the sync for him.